# raylib C++ Program Fails with GLFW Error on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Running Debian 11 (Bullseye)

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, glfw, raylib

I'm working on a C++ project using the `raylib` library on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. The program used to run without issues, but it suddenly started failing on startup with GLFW errors related to OpenGL context creation. Despite my efforts in reinstalling `raylib` and verifying OpenGL configurations, I've hit a roadblock. Here are the error messages I'm encountering:

```
INFO: Initializing raylib 5.1-dev
INFO: Platform backend: DESKTOP (GLFW)
INFO: Supported raylib modules:
INFO: > rcore:..... loaded (mandatory)
INFO: > rlgl:...... loaded (mandatory)
INFO: > rshapes:... loaded (optional)
INFO: > rtextures:. loaded (optional)
INFO: > rtext:..... loaded (optional)
INFO: > rmodels:... loaded (optional)
INFO: > raudio:.... loaded (optional)
WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65543 Description: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig
WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize Window
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Segmentation fault)
```

**Environment Details:**

- **OS**: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) running on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
- **Kernel**: 6.1.21-v8+ (aarch64)
- **Desktop Environment**: LXDE with X.Org X Server 1.20.11
- **OpenGL Version**: 2.1 Mesa 20.3.5 with renderer V3D 4.2
- **Display Environment Variable**: `:0`
- **C++ Compiler**: g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
- The program worked over X11 and VNC in the past, but now it fails to start in both environments.

`glxgears` runs perfectly, indicating that OpenGL 2.1 is functional, and `raylib` was reinstalled multiple times in an attempt to resolve the issue.

I'm seeking guidance on how to address these GLFW errors and successfully run my `raylib`-based program again. I will provide any further information necessary for troubleshooting.

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

I've narrowed down the problem to the following simple program, which should open a window and display some text using raylib. However, the program fails at initialization, specifically at the InitWindow() call.

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main(void) {
    InitWindow(800, 600, "Hello, raylib!");
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawText("Hello, raylib!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

In VScode debugging it shows me that the error happens in row 4 `InitWindow()`.

*Raylib exemples compile correctly:*
Following [github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-Raspberry-Pi) i compiled the examples in the libary with the same Make command given and those run well. i compile my code with: `` g++ main.cpp -o program `pkg-config --libs --cflags raylib` -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11 -latomic -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP ``

Here is an example of the Make command output of the working examples:

```
gcc -o others/rlgl_standalone others/rlgl_standalone.c -Wall -std=c99 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -Wunused -result -O2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -I. -/home/vacmeister/Desktop/MCI/Programmieren/MCIGraph/raylib/raylib/src -/home/vacmeister/Desktop/MCI/Programmieren/MCIGraph/raylib/raylib/src/external -I/usr/local/include -I/home/vacmeister/Desktop/MCI/Programmieren/MCIGraph/raylib/raylib/src/external/glfw/include -L. -L/home/vacmeister/Desktop/MCI/Programmieren/MCIGraph/raylib/raylib/src- /home/vacmeister/Desktop/MCI/Programmieren/MCIGraph/raylib/raylib/src -L/usr/local/l    ib -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11 -latomic -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP
```

Comment: It looks like you have a bad frame buffer configuration. Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have updated the post with an MRE and submitted for review. Please see above.

Comment: https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/796

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have tried your suggestion linked above. I recompiled with the flags, copied the new `libraylib.a` generated in the `/src` of the raylib libary to `/usr/local/lib/`. Than i recompiled my .cpp again but the same error remains.